# How can I decode an array formatted in json in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am setting up dialogflow in php to retrieve input from google assistant.

I want to use a parameter I got from dialogflow.

But I don't know how to get it out of the json.

I've already got a function that gets parameters from the json, but it's in a weird format.

How can I get only the pet_name in a variable?

The formats are:

When I use print_r I get:

```
Array
(
    [pet_name] => gizmo
)
```

And when I do var_dump I get:

```
array(1) {
  ["pet_name"]=>
  string(5) "gizmo"
}
```

Hope this makes it clearer

Comment: [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode).

Comment: Did you at least try `json decode php` on Google or something ?

Comment: yes, json_decode returns the error: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: share your code where you are using json_decode and getting error

Comment: edited my question, hope it makes it clearer.

Comment: @BastiaanBuitelaar then you don't have JSON, you have an array. Treat it like an array. Skip trying to decode it because it's either already been decoded for you, or was never JSON in the first place.

Comment: @Sammitch I did think that it was an array, but I used $array->pet_name instead of $array['pet_name']. Rookie mistake 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the name from your index as like:

```
<?
$string = '{"pet_name":"gizmo"}';
$parsed = json_decode($string);
echo $parsed->pet_name;
?>
```

if you are using true as a second param in [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) then this will return an array and you can get as like:

```
<?
$string = '{"pet_name":"gizmo"}';
$parsed = json_decode($string,true);
echo $parsed['pet_name'];
?>
```

Comment: If the last block of code I posted is my array, how does it work then?

Comment: @BastiaanBuitelaar: then it will be access as like `echo $parsed['pet_name'];`

Answer (score 1):

You can decode a JSON string using json_decode like so:

```
<?php

$parsed = json_decode("{\"pet_name\":\"gizmo\"}");

print_r($parsed);
```

Comment: json_decode returns the error: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: @BastiaanBuitelaar: then it means, u are using wrong way

Answer (score 1):

I eventually did

```
echo $parameters['pet_name'];
```

And YES it returned 'gizmo!';

Thanks for the help!